# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Worklight project created as JavaScript project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Have updated to Worklight 6.1 but when I try to create a new Worklight project it is created as a JavaScript project instead of Worklight project. How should I correct this?

Comment: What do you mean? What is being created? Please add an image or describe the full contents of the project. How do you create the project? What is your Eclipse version? Please reply to all questions.

Answer (score 0):

To create a JavaScript Project in Eclipse you would actually have to go through `File > New > Project > JavaScript Project`. For Worklight you would click on the `Worklight icon` in the toolbar. A very distinct project is created for each...

Make sure you are using Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) or 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1) and that you are indeed choosing to create a Worklight project.

In the image below:

- "test" is a JavaScript Project
- "test2" is a Worklight Project

Full size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/okvnX.png
    [image]

Comment: Yes, I am indeed creating a Worklight project - I've even stepped through the Worklight project creation wizard but the project that is created by Eclipse is a JavaScript project. I don't get the Worklight options when right-clicking on the folders in the project. Eclipse version 4.2.2. Mac OS X 10.9, Java 1.6 Worklight 6.1

Comment: Sounds like your installation was not successful... Id try with a new install of Eclipse and the plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace.